# inside for loop using if else with in between operator in javascript

Tags: javascript

Here is my code:

```
for(j=0;j<=240;j++) {
    if(j>0 && j<=2) {
        a="value : 012";
    }
    else if(j>2 && j<=5) {
        a="value : 345";
    }   
    else {
        a="7888...240";
    }
}
```

In this code if and else if condition not working. It always come into else condition only. I don't know why.

Comment: How do you know it always evaluates to `else`? Put magical `alert('you are wrong');` to any of `if` bodies and see you're wrong.

Comment: i used console.log("somthing")

Comment: When the for loop ends, a will have the else condition value. So, it makes you think that if and else if didn't work because you are re-assigning the same variable for each iteration.

Comment: @Saravanan M P: use alert to ensure your assumptions are incorrect

Comment: For the code _as shown_ the variable `a` will be repeatedly overwritten and when the loop ends `a` will be `"7888...240"`. So it might _seem_ like only the `else` is executing but that's not really the case. But you said in a comment that you used `console.log("somthing")` so you've obviously tried some other variations to what's shown - _where_ exactly did you put that log statement?

Answer (score 2):

Your code is fine. Each `a=` statement overrides the previous value. I made a slight change to show that it works fine.

http://jsfiddle.net/MthpM/1/

```
var a ="";

for(j=0;j<=240;j++)
{
    if(j>0 && j<=2)
    {
        a+="value : 012";
    }
    else if(j>2 && j<=5)
    {
         a+="value : 345";
    }   
    else
    {
         a+="value : 345";
}}


console.log(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
var a;

for (var j = 0; j <= 240; j++) {
    if (j > 0 && j <= 2) {
        a = "value : 012";
    }
    else if (j > 2 && j <= 5) {
        a = "value : 345";
    }   
    else {
        a = "7888...240";
    }
}
```

---

EDIT: Here is a fiddle that works with this code I answered with. http://jsfiddle.net/fYb8K/

I only added alert statements, like so:

```
var a;

for (var j = 0; j <= 240; j++) {
    if (j > 0 && j <= 2) {
        a = "value : 012";
       alert(a + "This worked for first if");
    }
    else if (j > 2 && j <= 5) {
        a = "value : 345";
        console.log(a);
        alert(a + "this worked for else if");
    }   
    else {
        a = "7888...240";
        console.log(a);
    }
}
```

As you'll notice if you go to the fiddle. It alerts 2 times for "this worked for first if"

And it alerts 3 times for "this worked for else if"

Comment: What have you changed?

Comment: @Saravanan M P: what "not working" means? It does work as expected

Comment: @AlienArrays: I didn't say it doesn't

Comment: @nnnnnn: and it's a valid answer. OP stated it doesn't evaluate `if` bodies and this answer proves it's not the case. I think a perfectly valid answer for the question. If OP wanted something else - they should have expressed it more obviously.

Comment: @zerkms - Sorry, I must've deleted my original comment while you were replying to it. My point was that repeating all of the OP's code and saying it "should work" isn't very helpful. The edit with the alerts and console log statements is much better, and as you say it proves that all three branches get executed. The answer would be better still if the edit had replaced the original version, and it would be perfect if it explicitly mentioned what the value of `a` will be after the loop and why that might make it seem at first glance that only the `else` occurred.